# Somehow I can’t instal Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, terminal, homebrew, zsh

As described on the homebrew site (https://brew.sh/) this should be pretty straightforward, just open the terminal, paste and run. However, somehow it is not working for me and now a couple of hours in, I am getting very frustrated.

I am a rookie and suspect this is some easy fix thing, so I would appreciate some help. I am on macOS Catalina, using `zsh`, and when I paste and run nothing happens, the cursor goes to the next line, and I can type, but nothing runs, no feedback. Which I understand is what happens when the command makes no sense. Instead I should be prompted very quickly to hit Return and continue with the installation.

I made sure the quotes are not changed, I tried using `Bash`, but somehow it’s not working. (Installed the command line tools as well).

Out of frustation I tried the alternative way described on the site (not sure I took the right steps):

- cd /usr/local
- pasted and ran:

```
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

In this case, I did get a directory called homebrew in `/usr/local/homebrew`

But brew was not added to `/bin`, so the command was not found when trying to run it. I deleted the homebrew dir as I figured solving this might’ve been more complicated.

I also ended up doing most of the things I found online about modifying the PATH, and using sudo but these only seemed to make things worse (had to reset my mac because something I did made it unusable after working smoothly)

If anyone can give me a hand I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Whats the error you are getting when you use this - `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` Its the first thing I see on brew.sh

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the command you run? Did you include the ``/bin/bash -c`` part?

Comment: @leoOrion I don’t get an error, when I hit enter nothing happens, the cursor goes to the next line and that’s it

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this is what I run: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

Comment: Can you try doing it in two steps. Do the curl alone. That will downlaod the `install.sh` file. Then call the `install.sh` file. Additionally. after you call the `install.sh`, do an `echo $?` and post what it returns. The echo command should be the immediate command after the isntall.sh is called.