# What is really the best (and secure) way to install Python on a Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew, macos-catalina

I am about to start a course on Python and I am just confused and overwhelmed about how to go about installing Python on my Mac running Catalina. For most of the articles I found a Homebrew approach was recommended, so I went down that path. Or at least I tried, but for some reason I couldn't install it even with something as simple as pasting and running on terminal. I then ended up messing with my files (I am a rookie, really didn't know what I was doing) trying to get brew working, but somehow using PATH, sudo, and /usr/local I ended up doing something to my OS that immediately made the system unresponsive and behave in weird ways.
Long story sort I ended up reseting the disk and starting from zero. I would really appreciate a guide into what really is the most secure way to get python on my Mac. After the experience I had trying with Homebrew, and doing a bit of research (reading things like this: https://applehelpwriter.com/2018/03/21/how-homebrew-invites-users-to-get-pwned/), I am really overwhelmed since I need to get python 3 and virtual env on my computer, but I don't want to put my system at risk due to my lack of experience and really understanding of what is going on with this different options.

Comment: If you are that concerned, maybe take a free tier AWS EC2 node and run your Python scripts on there. As a bonus, all your scripts and environment will be available unchanged and as you left it to you from home, class or a hotel on a weekend away or while on business.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend heading over to the [Python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and downloading Python from there. Just follow all the steps you are given which should be quite easy to follow and you have Python installed!

Comment: There seems to be some arguments against doing that too, for dependencies, package management, and some other issues I don't really comprehend. Why would you say this is the best and safest way? Is it optimal later for use of libraries and environments?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this script `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` on [the homepage](https://brew.sh/).

And then you can do `brew install python@3.8` or `brew install python`.

Homebrew is an OSS software with codebase available in github, feel free to do the security checks and submit the [hackerone reports](https://hackerone.com/homebrew).

Happy to answer any specific question.

Comment: Yes I tried but somehow I can't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753234/somehow-i-can-t-instal-homebrew?noredirect=1#comment110973998_62753234   Still my whole questions is about if I should be doing it that way.

Comment: It might be the permission setup and path setup. what is the error message that you have?

Comment: I suspect it might just work now, after reinstalling Catalina, but again I am trying to asses if that's the best thing to do. Before I actually didn't get any error messages, after hitting enter on terminal nothing would happen, I would get the zsh behavior for when what you typed made no sense.